# A question about gods

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, tantra

if I attain turiya state, do gods exist on that loka or not? because I do know that turiya is unmanifested state and we're indiffrent from Narayana/Purusha and we're very himself in turiya, and gods didn't exist till purushamedha yajna was performed and purusha was offered as main sacrifice, and from that sacrifice everything including gods came into being.

Comment: Gods are ruler of elements and part of Prakriti while Turiya is the state of nameless Purusha transcending Maya, the cause and brain behind Prakriti and its elements. Purusha is the programmer but Maya and Gods are the program. " Brahman was this before; therefore it knew even the Ātma (soul, himself). I am Brahman, therefore it became all. And whoever among the gods had this enlightenment, also became That. It is the same with the sages, the same with men. Whoever knows the self as “I am Brahman,” becomes all this universe. Even the gods cannot prevail against him, for he becomes their Ātma."

Comment: "Now, if a man worships another god, thinking: “He is one and I am another,” he does not know. He is like an animal to the gods. As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve the gods. Even if one animal is taken away, it causes anguish; how much more so when many are taken away? Therefore it is not pleasing to the gods that men should know this." — Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10

Comment: They, the gods and the lokas, will continue to exist for them, but they will cease to exist for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the turiya state with the manifestation of Devatas. Turiya is a state beyond the waking, dream and dreamless sleep state.

**Turiya**

> Thou liest in the Cosmic Waters in the state of Turiya, which is
> neither absorption in the oblivion of deep sleep, nor involvement in
> the objective movement of the waking and dream states.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana VII.9.30**

Devatas and for that matter the entire universe with its 14 lokas and jivas are manifestations of Brahman. Devatas and Jivas can be in the turiya state but one must not mix up the lokas with the Turiya state.